# What's the difference between adding and cloning a remote repository?

Tags: git

What's the difference between adding a remote repository and cloning a remote repository? I'm reading the pragmatic guide to git and they are talking about distributed environments and using git remote add. I'm finding the section difficult to understand, and why I should use it over clone.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git clone sets up a new repository similar to the one you are cloning ( hence the name clone!) and "adds" the remote repository from which you cloned as the remote with the name `origin`

Just doing the last part of setting up a remote is "adding a remote repository" and doing the whole thing and getting a new clone is cloning. Note that when you add a remote repository, you already have a repository. When you clone, you do not already have the repository.

A repository can have muliple `remotes` added to it via `git remote add`. Usually these are remote repositories of the same repo's clones on peers and servers with which you push and pull.

Comment: thanks man. that was a great answer. I wish the book had been that clear. I must have read the the same few pages 20 times trying to find something I'd missed.

Answer (score 8):

Using `git remote add` is connecting another (remote) repository to the current repository so you can pull and push with the remote repository. For example, I do this when I push things to Github, because I already have my own "master" repository as `origin`.

Using `git clone` creates a *new* repository on your local system that is set up to connect to a remote repository. I would do this when getting a clone of another published project from somewhere, or making another copy of one of my own projects (perhaps on a different computer).